# how to hide column in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to hide column if column's value is null in gridview

like

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PageData" >
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Literal ID="ltrInout" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PageData") %>' Visible='<%# (Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("PageData") == null))></asp:</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

by this way I am able to hide column but still header is showing on grid.

So how can I hide entire column from grid based on value.I don't want to hide from code behind.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set 'visible' attribute of the templatefield to 'false'.

Answer (score 0):

Null & DBNull are different. Use

```
Visible='<%# (Eval("RTMPageData") != DBNull.Value)
```

Comment: what if field return integer? this is not working.as I said I want to hide entire column,not only field.

Comment: there should be no problem with integers as Eval returns object. Regarding hiding entire column, what would you do if one row contained a value in that column & other did not?